# Best selfie pose

Tags: technique, self-portrait

I have tried various poses taking selfies, but I'm not getting a good result. Can anyone suggest poses to get the best picture?

Comment: It has not much sense recomending one pose. Probably the issue is another. Post an example of your photos to analize it.

Answer (score 2):

Specific poses are not easy to suggest. It really depends on what you find acceptable. What is useful is to place a mirror opposite where you want to sit or stand. It will let you adjust your pose because you can see how you look. The additional bonus is that it assists you to arrange the background so that your self portait image looks as good as you can make it. I estimate that you should be able to capture a pose which you find acceptable within five minutes of using a mirror to reflect your poses.